# Does keymando 1.2.2 support OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion?

Tags: keymando

Just installed the trial version of Keymando 1.2.2 on an instance of OSX Mountain Lion. Nothing seems to work - I add simple key maps, reload config, make sure Keymando is enabled - nothing happens.

If 1.2.2 should be fine on Mountain Lion, does anyone have any debug tips?

**Edit** I should be clear: I have never installed or used Keymando before, so the config is the basic one from the install. Here it is with the maps I added:

```
# Start Keymando at login
# -----------------------------------------------------------
start_at_login

# Disable Keymando when using these applications
# -----------------------------------------------------------
disable "Remote Desktop Connection"
# disable /VirtualBox/

# Basic mapping
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# map "<Ctrl-[>", "<Escape>"
# map "<Ctrl-m>", "<Ctrl-F2>"
map "<Ctrl-S>" { say "Keymando." }

# vi type movement, select
except /iTerm/, "MacVim" do
  map "<Ctrl-j>", "<Down>"
  map "<Ctrl-k>", "<Up>"
  map "<Ctrl-h>", "<Left>"
  map "<Ctrl-l>", "<Right>"
  map "<Ctrl-f>", "<PageUp>"
  map "<Ctrl-b>", "<PageDown>"

  map "<Ctrl-Shift-j>", "<Shift-Down>"
  map "<Ctrl-Shift-k>", "<Shift-Up>"
  map "<Ctrl-Shift-h>", "<Shift-Left>"
  map "<Ctrl-Shift-l>", "<Shift-Right>"

  # Right mouse click
  map "<Ctrl-r>" do
    right_click
    # alert(mouse_x)
  end

end

# Commands
# -----------------------------------------------------------

# Command launcher window via Cmd-Space
map "<Cmd- >" do                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  trigger_item_with(Commands.items, RunRegisteredCommand.new)                                                                                                                                                             
end 

# Register commands 
# -----------------------------------------------------------
command "Volume Up" do 
  `osascript -e 'set volume output volume (output volume of (get volume settings) + 7)'`
end

command "Volume Down" do 
  `osascript -e 'set volume output volume (output volume of (get volume settings) - 7)'`
end

# Repeat last command via Cmd-.
map "<Cmd-.>", RunLastCommand.instance
```

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You should ask this on http://apple.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I don't disagree, I'm just following the support instructions at keymando: http://keymando.com/contact/.

Answer (score 0):

Keymando 1.2.3 fixes this issue.

See:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/keymando/DuFYbAGxRFk
- http://updates.keymando.com/

Comment: Gotta disagree.  Still having tons of issues myself with 1.3.  Half of your own examples in the tutorials don't work.  Feel free to ping me if I can be of help getting this to work because I was looking for an AHK alternative, and this keeps coming up.  Doesn't do me any good if I can't get it to work.